# Electron data storage

Tags: javascript, mysql, nosql

I'm developing disktop app using electron I want to store my data loclly within the app (no internet connection)  I installed mysql using node js it worked but only if my laotop is connected to the internent

Answer (score 0):

You are writing html5 to create the application. Now you need to think what html5 provides to store data and it would be localStorage, WebSql and IndexedDB.

You can store data in mysql too but you need to install the mysql at users computer and it would be hard to create a package including mysql which will install mysql, return the right port so that you can use inside your electron application.

Now from three options (localStorage, WebSql and IndexedDB) - WebSql is deprecated , so you should not use it. localStorage is only good for storing data in terms of key and value with fix length. So the last option would be indexeddb.

So you should store data in indexeddb, although there are others options like - sqllite etc which you can use it using some third party driver.

If you find indexeddb difficult to use, consider using any of indexeddb library. Check the example for storing data in electron using indexeddb library jsstore - https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/tree/master/examples/electron